# Работа с файлами в Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt5

Написал вот такую ротацию логов в своей программе.

```
QFileInfo log("log.txt");
int currentM = QDate::currentDate().month();
int createM = log.created().toString("MM").toInt();
if (createM != 0)
{
    if (currentM > createM)
    {
        char oldn[] = "log.txt";
        char newn[] = "oldlog.txt";
        QFile::remove(newn);
        QFile::rename(oldn, newn);
    }
}
fileDebug = fopen("log.txt", "a+t");
fprintf(fileDebug, %s Log started\n, QDateTime:: currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy").toLocal8Bit().constData());
qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);
```

Каждый месяц лог, который записывался, переименовывается в oldlog, старый oldlog перед этим удаляется. Затем программа создает новый файл с именем log, и пишет уже в него.

Проблема состоит в том, что новый файл log.txt создаётся с датой создания старого лога, и я не могу понять почему.

При этом, если оба лога удалить - и старый, и новый - то есть программе нечего будет удалять и переименовывать, она создаст новый лог с нормальной датой создания.

Проверял, что remove и rename точно работают.
Пробовал добавлять деструктор класса QFileInfo сразу после получения даты - не помогло.

Почему программа так делает? Как заставить её создавать файл с правдивой датой создания?

Comment: вы ж в Qt, зачем вам такие сложности? пишите через QFile и для очистки файла открывайте его c Write, а для добавления с Append

Comment: что то странное: ротация логов в приложении на qt - ваше приложение с графикой и включено на протяжении дней? Почему бы не использовать logrotate вместо кастомной утилиты?

Comment: ОС? на *nix-системах `created()` возвращал ctime, а это совсем не время создания и ты бы скорей всего это заметил... про win ничего достоверно утверждать не смогу, но ЕМНИП там как раз та проблема на которую ты напоролся: если пересоздавать файл слишком быстро, то Creation Time не меняется... собственно не используй `created()` для этих целей — он врёт...

Comment: Вообще, я проверял не только через отладку, но и сами файлы. Заходил в их свойства через проводник, и видел ту же самую дату, что выдает created. Видимо, да, слишком быстро создаёт, буду думать, как развести эти действия в коде. Будет непросто, учитывая, что этот алгоритм выполняется при запуске приложения, и замедлять запуск обычной паузой не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Qt нет инструментов для изменения даты файла, но это можно сделать средствами WinAPI. Тогда файл придётся создавать не с помощью fopen, а с помощью [CreateFileA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea). Функция для изменения времени: [SetFileTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime).

```
#include <Windows.h>

HANDLE file = CreateFileA("D:\\1.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
   // Failed to create file
   return 2;
}
FILETIME time;
GetFileTime(file, &time, NULL, NULL);
time.dwHighDateTime -= 1500;
//                создан, открыт, изменён
SetFileTime(file, &time, &time, &time);
```

Comment: Зачем WinAPI, если есть стандартный `<filesystem>`?